# I want summarise a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want summarize the following data frame to a summary table.

```
plot <- c(rep(1,2), rep(2,4), rep(3,3))
bird <- c('a','b', 'a','b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c')
area <- c(rep(10,2), rep(5,4), rep(15,3))
```

```
birdlist <- data.frame(plot,bird,area)
birdlist
```

```
  plot bird area
1    1    a   10
2    1    b   10
3    2    a    5
4    2    b    5
5    2    c    5
6    2    d    5
7    3    a   15
8    3    b   15
9    3    c   15
```

I tried the following

```
birdlist %>% 
  group_by(plot, area) %>% 
  mutate(count(bird))
```

I am trying to get a data frame as result that looks like the following

```
plot bird area
   1    2   10
   2    4   5
   3    3   15
```

Please help/advice on how to count `bird` with reference to `plot` and respective `area` of the `plot`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You were very close, you want `summarize` instead of `mutate` though and you can use `n()` to count the number of rows within the group you're specifying.

```r
library(tidyverse)
birdlist %>%
  group_by(plot, area) %>%
  summarize(bird = n(),
            .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    plot  area  bird
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1    10     2
#> 2     2     5     4
#> 3     3    15     3
```

If you're set on `count`, you would use it without `group_by`.

```
birdlist %>%
  count(plot, area, name = "bird")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I was getting an error. ```birdlist %>%
+   group_by(plot, area) %>%
+   summarize(bird = n(),
+             .groups = "drop")
Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.```

Comment: Ah, you probably have conflicting packages. run it as dplyr::summarize

Comment: I still have the problem.

Comment: Done!!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. When you load packages you'll get a warning which function names have a conflict so make sure to look at that. I get this often with `dplyr` and `rms` for the `summarize` function. When that happens you have to specifically reference the package you want to call the function from (i.e. dplyr::summarize) or R will use whatever the most recent loaded package was.

Answer (score 3):

We could `group_by` `plot` and `summarise` using `unique()`:

```
birdlist %>% 
  group_by(plot) %>% 
  summarise(bird = n(), area = unique(area))
```

```
     plot  bird  area
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1     2    10
2     2     4     5
3     3     3    15
```